# Como generar un archivo xml y descargarlo con jquery en c# asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, xml

les explico mi problema, estoy generando un proyecto web en C# asp.net donde consumo un web service que extrae desde una base de datos un string almacenado con formato xml, ese string en algún momento del proyecto debo traerlo y descargarlo en un archivo xml por medio de jquery.

Este es el código donde extraigo mi cadena de la base de datos

```
public string consultarXMLTitulo(string numControl) 
    {
        string a = "";
        
        using (objAcceso = new AccesoDatos(false))
        {
            objAcceso.StoreProcedure.Nombre = "pa_STD_Titulos_Electronicos_XML";
            objAcceso.StoreProcedure.Parametros.Add("@NumControl", numControl);
            a = objAcceso.EjecutarCommand(ENUM_EXECUTECOMMAND.SCALAR).ToString();
        }
        return a;            
    }
```

La cadena que obtengo a través de esa consulta es la siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en mi web service es donde recibo esa cadena extraída de la base de datos, luego la cargo dentro de un documento xml y posteriormente es recibido por el javascript

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public XmlDocument estatusTitulo(string numeroControl)
        {
            
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            try
            {
                TitulosDigitalesDAO dao = new TitulosDigitalesDAO()
                doc.LoadXml(dao.consultarXMLTitulo(numeroControl));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            return doc;
            
        }
```

Dentro de mi javascript recibo esa documento xml con el nombre de result, hago el procedimiento para descargar el archivo

```
function sepudo(result) {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = result;
    a.download = "pruebatitulo" + ".xml";
    a.click();
}
```

pero al momento de ejecutarse el navegador no muestra el archivo descargado, necesito ayuda :(
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que noto es que asignas lo que obtienes de la llamada ajax directo al link

```
function sepudo(result) 
{
    var blob = new Blob(result);
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download = "pruebatitulo.xml";
    link.click();
}
```

cuando deberias asignarlo a un `Blob` para que genere la url de descarga

Comment: Funciono ! Muchas gracias!!